# After knowing the exact position of a feature in an image, track it on all subsequent frames

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have a computationally expensive way of finding the exact bounding box of a feature in an image. On all subsequent images, the feature could have moved. I want to avoid doing this computationally expensive process on every frame. Is there a technique to use something like background subtraction + contour detection to track a feature after its bounding box is known once?

Comment: try openCV 3.1's TLD Tracking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Object Tracking using OpenCV (C++/Python)](https://www.learnopencv.com/object-tracking-using-opencv-cpp-python/)

python sample code from the link:

```
import cv2
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__' :

# Set up tracker.
# Instead of MIL, you can also use
# BOOSTING, KCF, TLD, MEDIANFLOW or GOTURN

tracker = cv2.Tracker_create("MIL")

# Read video
video = cv2.VideoCapture("videos/chaplin.mp4")

# Exit if video not opened.
if not video.isOpened():
    print "Could not open video"
    sys.exit()

# Read first frame.
ok, frame = video.read()
if not ok:
    print 'Cannot read video file'
    sys.exit()

# Define an initial bounding box
bbox = (287, 23, 86, 320) # x, y, width, height

# Uncomment the line below to select a different bounding box
# bbox = cv2.selectROI(frame, False)

# Initialize tracker with first frame and bounding box
ok = tracker.init(frame, bbox)

while True:
    # Read a new frame
    ok, frame = video.read()
    if not ok:
        break

    # Update tracker
    ok, bbox = tracker.update(frame)

    # Draw bounding box
    if ok:
        p1 = (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]))
        p2 = (int(bbox[0] + bbox[2]), int(bbox[1] + bbox[3]))
        cv2.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, (0,0,255))

    # Display result
    cv2.imshow("Tracking", frame)

    # Exit if ESC pressed
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
    if k == 27 : break
```

Hope this help!

Comment: What is the order of points in the bounding box? I get [this error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43593444/opencv-tracker-the-model-is-not-initialized-in-function-init) when I try this method

Comment: a tuple with 4 value by following orders: 1. x coordinate of top left point of the bounding box
2. y coordinate of top left point of the bounding box
3. width of the bounding box
4. height of the bounding box

Comment: How can a coordinate be 1 value?